# Reactive Extensionを使用して、ボタンリストの何番目のボタンが押されたかを知るには

Tags: c#, unity3d

UniRx(Unity用Reactive Extension)を使用して、
カードリストのような画面を作成しようとしています。

個別のボタンであれば、ボタンと対になる処理を書けば良いので、
クリック通知があったらSubscribeに〜する。といった書き方ができますが
リスト構造の場合、ボタンが押されただけではどこのインデックスのボタンが
押されかがわかりません。

.netの新しいバージョンであればObeservableCollectionなどが使えそうなのですが、
Unityでは使用できませんでした。

MVPパターンで作成しているので、
データのやり取りはあくまでModel側がおこない
イベントやアクションなどはView側が受け持って
Model側とView側のやり取りは、Presenter側に書きます。

ですので、どこのインデックスのボタンが押されたかは
View側に書きたいのですが、どのように関連付ければ良いのかがわかりません。

考え方やサンプルソースなどを教えていただけないでしょうか？

追記：IndexOfを使って自分自身を検索するようにしようとしたのですが、
　　　ラムダ式の中で自分自身を渡す方法がわからず。
　　　IObservable`<Unit>`のUnitではなく、IObservable`<Unit>`を渡したい

```
/// <summary>
/// ボタンのリスト
/// </summary>
public List<Button> ButtonList = new List<Button>();
/// <summary>
/// ボタンイベント通知リスト
/// </summary>
List<IObservable<Unit>> abc = new List<IObservable<Unit>>();
/// <summary>
/// ボタン通知のハッシュリスト
/// </summary>
List<int> abcHash = new List<int>();

void Start () 
{
    abc.Add(ButtonList[0].OnClickAsObservable());
    abcHash.Add(abc[0].GetHashCode());

    abc.Add(ButtonList[1].OnClickAsObservable());
    abcHash.Add(abc[1].GetHashCode());

    abc.Add(ButtonList[2].OnClickAsObservable());
    abcHash.Add(abc[2].GetHashCode());

    abc.Add(ButtonList[3].OnClickAsObservable());
    abcHash.Add(abc[3].GetHashCode());

    foreach(IObservable<Unit> test in abc)
    {
        test.Subscribe(
            _ => ButtonClicked(abcHash.IndexOf(test自身のハッシュ値を取得したい)))
            );
    }
}

private void ButtonClicked(int index)
{
    Debug.Log("index=" + index.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

各ループ中の変数に`i`の値を代入しておけばラムダ式から参照できます。

```
for(int i = 0; i < abc.Count; i++)
{
    int n = i; // ループ内の変数に代入
    abc[i].Subscribe(
        _ => ButtonClicked(n)
        );

}
```

なお`i`のスコープは各ループの外であるため最終的に値が`abc.Count`となり、参照すると意図した動作にはなりません。

Comment: そうなんです、押す瞬間にはその瞬間のインデックスではないため、
押されたもののハッシュを渡してハッシュチエックでインデックスをと思ったのですが、押された瞬間のUnitのハッシュが０なので取得できないです。

Comment: @user3732298 ええと、それは`i`を直接参照した場合の話でしょうか？上のコードでは`Unit`のハッシュコードは全く使用していませんよ？`Unit`のインスタンスは何ら情報を持っていないので、そちらからボタンを判断するのは無理です。

Comment: すいません、編集した自分のコードの話です。　悩んでみてボタン自身のハッシュリストを持っておいて、Subscribeした時にハッシュ値から自分のINDEXを引っ張ってこれないかとやってみたのです。　ですがラムダ式の中に<Unit>ではなIObservable<Unit>がわからず。　Unit自身は情報を持ってないので判断できずという所で立ち止まってます。

Answer (score 0):

ViewはPresenterに何を渡すんですか？
`List<Button>`ですか？
`List<IObservable<Unit>>`ですか？

コードでpublicになっているので`List<Button>`で渡すとするなら、

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>(){ new Button() , new Button() , new Button() };

//------

foreach(var x in buttonList)
{
    x.OnClickAsObservable().Subscribe(_ => ButtonClicked(buttonList.IndexOf(x)));
}

buttonList[0].Click(); //-> index=0
buttonList[1].Click(); //-> index=1
buttonList[2].Click(); //-> index=2
```

`List<IObservable<Unit>>`で渡そうとするなら
そもそも通知したいのは「何番のボタンが押された」ですので、
`IObservable<int>`で渡すほうがいいと思います。